# If I bring up a UIActionSheet, how do I make one of the options segue to a new view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, segue, uiactionsheet

I really have no idea how to do this. I created the `UIActionSheet`, it comes up when I tap a button, but I want, upon a certain option being selected for the app to segue to a new view controller.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: The action sheet will invoke a method of its delegate and pass in the index of the button pressed. You implement that method and evaluate the button index and then perform the segue. So where is your problem here? Don't you know about the action sheet delegate or don't you know how to perform a segue programmatically or are you trying to automate this within your storyboard (which to my knowledge is not possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call in the UIActionSheetDelegate method (when the user taps the button) `[self performSegueWithIdentifyer:@"segue_id"];`

Comment: What's the segue id? And how do I specify which view controller it segues to?

Comment: I assumed you are using storyboards. In that case a segue is represented with that arrow connecting 2 ViewControllers. Every segue can have an ID, and can be triggered by the method I mentioned. The destination ViewController is the VC the arrow points to.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Delegate` method of `UIActionSheet` ([– actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIModalViewDelegate_Protocol/UIActionSheetDelegate/UIActionSheetDelegate.html))

```
#pragma mark - UIActionSheet Delegate Methods

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        // code for Button 1 
    }
    if(buttonIndex == 1)
    {
       // code for Button 2
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the segue id? And how do I specify which view controller it segues to?

Comment: @DougSmith - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868116/ios-5-load-view-from-uiactionsheet-button